# Compare Fields MS-Access 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to compare an input from a drop down in an entry form with a column name of my DB, if they match then true, otherwise false. 
The function I've built below is only returning false.

Input:

```
tmp = DLookup("[Column Name]", "DB", "Val = '" & Forms![Entry Form]!DB.Value & "'")
```

Function:

```
Function FieldExist(ByVal strField As String) As Boolean
Dim TableSet As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set TableSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
TableSet.activeconnection = CurrentProject.Connection
TableSet.Open ("ContactList")

    For i = 0 To TableSet.Fields.Count - 1
        If strField = TableSet.Fields.Item(i).Name Then
        FieldExists = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i

FieldExists = False
End Function
```

I believe that the line in the function causing the issue is the declaration of the strField variable. Namely:

```
        If strField = TableSet.Fields.Item(i).Name Then
```

Comment: What happens if you use the debugger to step through the code? Which line is not performing as you would expect? Also, please provide a description of your table, and also the value of `Forms![Entry Form]!DB.Value`.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://forums.devarticles.com/microsoft-access-development-49/check-if-a-field-exists-in-a-table-using-vba-58559.html